# Spring Batch + Hibernate: Resolve ManyToMany on Data Migration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-batch, data-migration

We are doing a data migration from one database to another using Hibernate and Spring Batch. The example below is slightly disguised.

Therefore, we are using the standard processing pipeline:

```
return jobBuilderFactory.get("migrateAll")
               .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(DConfiguration.migrateD())
```

and migrateD consists of three steps:

```
@Bean(name="migrateDsStep")
    public Step migrateDs() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("migrateDs")
                .<org.h2.D, org.mssql.D> chunk(100)
                .reader(dReader())
                .processor(dItemProcessor)
                .writer(dWriter())
                .listener(chunkLogger)
                .build();
```

Now asume that this table has a manytomany relationship to another table. How can I persist that? I have basically a JPA Entity Class for all my Entities and fill those in the processor which does the actual migration from the old database objects to the new ones.

```
@Component
@Import({mssqldConfiguration.class, H2dConfiguration.class})
public class ClassificationItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<org.h2.d, org.mssql.d> {

    public ClassificationItemProcessor() {
        super();
    }

    public Classification process(org.h2.d a) throws Exception {

        d di = new di();
        di.setA(a.getA);
        di.setB(a.getB);`

        // asking for object e.g. possible via, But this does not work:
        // Set<e> es = eRepository.findById(a.getes());
        di.set(es)
        ...
        // How to model a m:n?

        return d;
    }
```

So I could basically ask for the related object via another database call (Repository) and add it to d. But when I do that, I rather run into LazyInitializationExceptions or, if it was successful sometimes the data in the intermediate tables will not have been filled up.

What is the best practice to model this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Spring Batch issue, it is rather a Hibernate mapping issue. As far as Spring Batch is concerned, your input items are of type `org.h2.D` and your output items are of type `org.mssql.D`. It is up to you define what an item is and how to "enrich" it in your item processor.

You need to make sure that items received by the writer are completely "filled in", meaning that you have already set any other entities on them (be it a single entity or a set of of entities such as `di.set(es)` in your example). If this leads to lazy intitialization exceptions, you need to change your model to be eagerly initialized instead, because Spring Batch cannot help at that level.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will try that.

Comment: I can confirm that this solved the issue. Thank you again for this precise answer! I marked your answer as accepted. :)